# How to save text entered in EditText after orientation changed?

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-orientation, android-lifecycle

I have two activities:
1.Main Activity which contains listview;
2.Second Activity which add item to listview in Main Activity.

For Second Activity I created layout-land layout for landscape.

After Second Activity is opens in portrait, I change it to landscape mode - Second Activity close and app return to Main Activity.

**Questions**: 
1.How save entered to EditText fields values after orientation is changed?

2.And how to apply layout-land to Second Activity when change screen orientation to landscape?

**UPD**
Second activity code:

```
public class AddItem extends MainScreen implements OnClickListener{
final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";
EditText comment_enter, link_enter, password_enter, login_enter, title_enter, date_enter;
Button add_item_button, add_more_button, clear_close_button;
CheckBox showPass;
DBHelper db;
DataBase DB;
SimpleCursorAdapter passListViewAdapter;
SimpleDateFormat sdf;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.add_item);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "before edit : ");

    comment_enter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.comment_enter);
    link_enter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.link_enter);
    password_enter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_enter);
    login_enter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_enter);
    title_enter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title_enter);
    date_enter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date_enter);

    showPass = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.showPass);
       showPass.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "is checked : " + isChecked);
            if (isChecked) {
                password_enter.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
            } 
            else {
                password_enter.setInputType(129);
            }
        }
    });

    add_item_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_item_button);
    add_item_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Log.d(LOG_TAG, "add_item_button : ");
             String title_str = title_enter.getText().toString();
             String login_str = login_enter.getText().toString();
             String pass_str = password_enter.getText().toString();
             String link_str = link_enter.getText().toString();
             String comm_str = comment_enter.getText().toString();
             String date_str = date_enter.getText().toString();
                 byte[] login_byted = null;
                try {
                    login_byted = login_str.getBytes("UTF-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                 String login_crypted = Base64.encodeToString(login_byted, Base64.DEFAULT);
                 Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Crypted login" + login_crypted);

                 byte[] pass_byted = null;
                try {
                    pass_byted = pass_str.getBytes("UTF-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                 String pass_crypted = Base64.encodeToString(pass_byted, Base64.DEFAULT);
                  Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Crypted login" + pass_crypted);
             DataBase DB = new DataBase(AddItem.this);
             DB.open();

             DB.insertPass(title_str, login_crypted, pass_crypted, link_str, comm_str, date_str);
             DB.close();
             Log.d(LOG_TAG, "after inserting into DB : ");
             finish();
        }
    });

    add_more_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_more_button);
    add_more_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Log.d(LOG_TAG, "add_more_button : ");
             String title_str = title_enter.getText().toString();
             String login_str = login_enter.getText().toString();
             String pass_str = password_enter.getText().toString();
             String link_str = link_enter.getText().toString();
             String comm_str = comment_enter.getText().toString();
             String date_str = date_enter.getText().toString();
             byte[] login_byted = null;
                try {
                    login_byted = login_str.getBytes("UTF-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                 String login_crypted = Base64.encodeToString(login_byted, Base64.DEFAULT);
              Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Crypted login" + login_crypted);

              byte[] pass_byted = null;
                try {
                    pass_byted = pass_str.getBytes("UTF-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                 String pass_crypted = Base64.encodeToString(pass_byted, Base64.DEFAULT);
               Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Crypted login" + pass_crypted);
             DataBase DB = new DataBase(AddItem.this);
             DB.open();
             DB.insertPass(title_str, login_crypted, pass_crypted, link_str, comm_str, date_str);
             DB.close();
             Log.d(LOG_TAG, "after inserting into DB : ");
             fieldClear();
             String link_enter_str = link_enter.getText().toString();
            if(link_enter_str.equals("")){
                    link_enter.setText("http://www.");
            }
        }
    });

    clear_close_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clear_close_button);
    clear_close_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Log.d(LOG_TAG, "clear/close click button : ");
             boolean checkRes = emptyAllCheck();
             Log.d(LOG_TAG, "result : " + checkRes);
             if(checkRes == true){
                 finish();
             }
             fieldClear();
        }
    });

    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "title : " + savedInstanceState.getString("title"));
        title_enter.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("title")); 
        login_enter.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("login"));
        password_enter.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("pass"));
        link_enter.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("link"));
        comment_enter.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("comm"));
        date_enter.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("date"));
        add_item_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_item_button);
        add_more_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_more_button);
        }
    else {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "before getting date : ");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    String date = sdf.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    date_enter.setText(date);
    }

}

@Override
    protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    finish();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onPause : ");
    }

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

}

protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle saveInstance) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(saveInstance);

    String title_str = title_enter.getText().toString();
     String login_str = login_enter.getText().toString();
     String pass_str = password_enter.getText().toString();
     String link_str = link_enter.getText().toString();
     String comm_str = comment_enter.getText().toString();
     String date_str = date_enter.getText().toString();
     saveInstance.putString("title", title_str);
     saveInstance.putString("login", login_str);
     saveInstance.putString("pass", pass_str);
     saveInstance.putString("link", link_str);
     saveInstance.putString("comm", comm_str);
     saveInstance.putString("date", date_str);
     Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onSaveInstanceState +" + title_str + login_str + pass_str + link_str + comm_str + date_str);
  }

public void fieldClear(){
    comment_enter.setText("");
    link_enter.setText("http://www.");
    password_enter.setText("");
    login_enter.setText("");
    title_enter.setText("");
}

public boolean emptyAllCheck(){
    String title_str = title_enter.getText().toString();
     String login_str = login_enter.getText().toString();
     String pass_str = password_enter.getText().toString();
     String link_str = link_enter.getText().toString();
     String comm_str = comment_enter.getText().toString();
    if (title_str.equals("") && login_str.equals("") && pass_str.equals("") && link_str.equals("http://www.") && comm_str.equals("")) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
  }
```

Comment: I this this is what you're looking for: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject

Comment: @naz013: does second activity only have landscape mode?
Can you elaborate your problem more briefly so I can help you.

Comment: No, Second activity has both (portrait and landscape layouts), but when I change orientation app close second activity and return to main activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i advise you to read a bit more about Android Activity life cycle it will help you.
However on configuration Change android destroy you are activity and recreate and you can use the callback method OnsavedInstanceState() to save you instance (it will be call automatically by the system on configuration change)

example

```
    public   void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);{
        String savedText =  myEditText.getText().toString();
        savedInstanceState.putString("Key", savedText);
   }
```

Now when the app is recreated on OnCreate method retrieve your saved text as follow :

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(savedInstanceState != null){
                myEditText.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("Key"); 
  //the rest of the code}
```

Voila and I hope that is that you meant.

Comment: Thank you! It work, data saves. But maybe you know how fix closing Second activity when I rotate to landscape?

Comment: Since you added the land layout i cant really know what is going on here unless you provide me some codes ! but make sure that all ID created on portrait layout are present in land layout and  identical and also make sure that the xml file present in you land package is the same name as the one in portrait. And if still not working provide us your codes.

Comment: I add full code of second activity. And one more thing: when I open second activity in landscape orientation it automatically use layout-land, but when I turn to portrait activity also close and return to Main.

Comment: Dude because at onPause you call finish(); and as i said on configuration change the system will close your activity and recreate it again, sp it will start first by calling call on onPause then onStop()... still onDestroy() methods however it will not recreate the activity because you call the method finish() inside the onPause() method.try to remove the finish() and try again and let me know, i hope it help

Comment: Oh thank you! I copy onPause from my other activity and forgot delete finish() from them.

Answer (score -2):

**use this one:**

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

add this code in your manifest file. No need to save the edit text variable.

Comment: -1, sorry. This should be used as a last resource, and saving a `EditText` data is a pretty simple operation to do to be done this way.